# Why does MacOS terminal switch positions of characters when copying a string with non-break space?

Tags: bash, macos

consider the following code:

```html
1&nbsp;2
```

Run the code. If you copy the resulting string "1 2" into an MacOS text editor (say TextEdit) and copy the code again into the MacOS terminal the positioning of "1 2" is switched to "21" (at least in my experience).

Why does the MacOS terminal show this behaviour? 
How does a non-breaking space modify the copy and paste functions in MacOS?

PS: I have not tested it for any other OS or terminal, yet.

Comment: I am getting it as `1 2` only. I am using macOS Catelina

Comment: I think it depends a lot of where you copy it from too. I'm copying it from Firefox and the string has a simple space between the 1 and the 2, which certainly wouldn't lead to the behaviour you encounter. Some other browser could have you copy the nonbreakable space or possibly some other character.